# Finding (2) newlines and replacing with (1)

Tags: atom-editor

Dumb question, in Atom, how do you replace (2) newlines with (1)?

[image]

Comment: That search should work as long as you're using Unix type line terminators (LF)

Comment: I used '''\n\n''', but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try ‘\r\n‘ (DOS cr+on)

Comment: Bingo, that was it.
https://github.com/atom/line-ending-selector